# Understanding Concurrency in FastAPI with a Synchronous Function

Tags: asynchronous, fastapi, openai-api

I have a FastAPI endpoint defined as follows:

```
@router.post("/v1/random")
def get_random():
    return generate_random_text()
```

This endpoint calls the generate_random_text function, which is structured as below:

```
def generate_random_text(
):
    prompt = “Generate random text”

    def event_stream():
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model=target_version,
            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": target_prompt}],
            max_tokens=1300,
            temperature=1,
            stream=True,
        )
        for line in completion:
            if line.choices[0].delta.get("content"):
                yield f"data: {line.choices[0].delta.get('content')}\n\n"
        yield "data: [DONE]\n\n"

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    }

    return StreamingResponse(event_stream(), headers=headers)
```

My question concerns the behavior of this endpoint when accessed simultaneously by multiple clients. When I test the endpoint with three different clients at the same time, all of them receive streaming responses immediately, despite the fact that the function is synchronous (I have not used async/await keywords).

How is it possible for all clients to receive immediate responses from a synchronous function? My understanding was that synchronous I/O operations in Python are blocking, which should prevent this concurrent handling of requests.

Could someone explain how this concurrent behavior is achieved in FastAPI with a synchronous function?